# Woo-Commerce REST API response correct on Postman not in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am implementing a "POST" api for creating an order through woo-commerce:

```
POST http://www.url.in/wp-json/wc/v1/orders
```

I am also using external library Oauth1 for it which uses one-legged authentication for it. Now when I run the API on Postman, it gives me correct response, but in the code it gives me error:

```
{
    "code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_create",
    "message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to create resources.",
    "data":{"status":401}
}
```

In my code I am creating a NSDictionary , I change it to NSData through NSJSONSerialization and sending it as HTTPBody along with the request.

Check the attached screen shot of Postman and Xcode.
[[image: Postman[1]]

[image: Xcode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lied in the JSON data I was posting. Instead of posting NSDictionary , I had to post it as NSString. It worked like a charm after that.